# Save a nested list into new smaller lists with python

Tags: python, nested-loops

I have a list(thislist), i split it in smaller lists(nested) and i want to take each index of the nested list and save it in different list,array etc

```
thislist = [39.435138344488145, 22.73229454094485, 39.43684333469196, 22.73215634579526, 39.43681019007974, 22.731609175156223, 39.43507007579199, 22.731759378861057, 39.43511979394629, 22.732236812065707, 39.435138344488145, 22.73229454094485]

n = 2

def divide_chunks(l, n):
    for i in range(0, len(l), n):
        yield l[i:i + n]

x = list(divide_chunks(thislist, n))
print(x)
```

I expect the output to be like:

```
list1=[39.435138344488145, 22.73229454094485]
list2=[39.43684333469196, 22.73215634579526]
list3= [39.43681019007974, 22.731609175156223]
etc
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you split a list into evenly sized chunks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/312443/how-do-you-split-a-list-into-evenly-sized-chunks)

Comment: @Sayse He is already splitting it. His code works. Its a different problem.

Comment: Do you just want it to print that way? Or do you want to create variable for each sublist?

Comment: @Error-SyntacticalRemorse - In that case its unclear what the op is asking

Comment: He wants to assign each sublist generated by `divide_chunks` to a separate variable.

Comment: @Sayse I agree 100%.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can you dynamically create variables via a while loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5036700/how-can-you-dynamically-create-variables-via-a-while-loop)

Answer (score 0):

Try this out-

```
chunks = [thislist[x:x+2] for x in range(0, len(thislist), 2)]
list_dict = {i: chunks[i] for i in range(0, len(chunks))}
g = globals()
for i in range(0, len(chunks)):
    g['list{0}'.format(i)] = list_dict[i]
```

This should give you your desired output! :)

Comment: Thank you a lot! And how can i save it in different lists?

Comment: Edited the answer to do that as well. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want:

```
thislist = [39.435138344488145, 22.73229454094485, 39.43684333469196, 22.73215634579526, 39.43681019007974, 22.731609175156223, 39.43507007579199, 22.731759378861057, 39.43511979394629, 22.732236812065707, 39.435138344488145, 22.73229454094485]

n = 2

def divide_chunks(l, n):
    for i in range(0, len(l), n):
        yield l[i:i + n]

for index, x in enumerate(divide_chunks(thislist, n)):
    exec("list{} = x".format(index + 1))
try:
    print(list1)
except NameError:
    print("Not a valid list")
```

That being said you are better off just doing list indexing for most use cases. (Using `exec` and `eval` is usually not recommended).